# Write access violation - **this**

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to refactor some code to use pointers and am running into a write access violation on my function calls.

I'm making these edits because my homework project requires the usage of the -> member operator as well as constructors and destructors.

One more edit: the input file worked just fine when I was formerly working without pointers, but the moment I added pointers everything broke.

Here's my code:
In main.cpp:

```
#include "student.h"

int main()
{
    /*
    TODO:
    2. Implement the class such that member pointers can be used to access the members.
    3. Implement pointers that point to each of the students' test scores as well as the average test score.
    */

    const int numStudents = 15;                     // Number of students
    Student * students = new Student[numStudents];  // Dynamically allocated array of Student objects
    Student ** studentsPtr = &students;

    // Starting file stream for studentRecords.dat
    ifstream student_records("student_records.dat");

    // Error checking for file loading
    if (!student_records)
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: The record file could not be opened for reading." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // Load data from file
    string current_value;
    stringstream newval;

    int tempID;
    string tempName;
    double tempTestScore;

    for (int index = 0; index < numStudents; index++)
    {
        // Store the student ID
        getline(student_records, current_value);
        newval << current_value;
        newval >> tempID;
        studentsPtr[index]->setID(tempID);
        newval.clear();

        // Store the student first name
        getline(student_records, current_value);
        newval << current_value;
        newval >> tempName;
        studentsPtr[index]->setFirstName(tempName);
        newval.clear();

        // Store the student last name
        getline(student_records, current_value);
        newval << current_value;
        newval >> tempName;
        studentsPtr[index]->setLastName(tempName);
        newval.clear();

        // Add each test score.
        for (int testScoreIndex = 0; testScoreIndex < numTests; testScoreIndex++)
        {
            getline(student_records, current_value);
            newval << current_value;
            newval >> tempTestScore;
            studentsPtr[index]->addTestScore(tempTestScore, testScoreIndex);
            newval.clear();
        }

        // Calculate the student's average
        students[index].calculateAverage();
    }

    // Print all data
    for (int index = 0; index < numStudents; index++)
    {
        studentsPtr[index]->printAll();
    }

    delete[] students;  // Free memory pointed to by students array
    students = NULL;    // Clear the memory.

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

In student.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int numTests = 10;

// Student class declaration
class Student
{
private:
    // Student ID and name
    int id;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;

    // List of student test scores
    // vector<double> testScores;
    double * testScores = new double[numTests];

    // Student average test score
    double average;

public:
    Student()       // Default constructor
    {
        const int numTests = 10;

        id = 0;
        firstName = " ";
        lastName = " ";
        average = 0.0;
    }

    ~Student()  // Destructor
    {
        delete[] testScores;
    }

    void setID(int);                // Set the student ID
    void setFirstName(string);      // Set the student name
    void setLastName(string);
    void addTestScore(double, int); // Add a test score to the vector
    void calculateAverage();        // Calculate the average of all test scores

    void printAll();                // Output all data to the screen for a given student
};
```

In student.cpp:

```
    #include "student.h"

// setID sets the id value.
void Student::setID(int studentID)
{
    id = studentID;
}

// setName sets the name value.
void Student::setFirstName(string studentFirstName)
{
    firstName = studentFirstName;
}

void Student::setLastName(string studentLastName)
{
    lastName = studentLastName;
}

// addTestScore adds a test score to the vector
void Student::addTestScore(double testScore, int index)
{
    testScores[index] = testScore;
    // testScores.push_back(testScore);
}

// calculateAverage adds every test score from the vector and divides them by the number of test scores in the list.
void Student::calculateAverage()
{
    double totalScores = 0.0;

    // for (double index : testScores)
    for (int index = 0; index < numTests; index++)
    {
        totalScores += testScores[index];
    }

    average = totalScores / numTests;
}

// printAll prints all the data to the screen.
void Student::printAll()
{
    cout << "=========================================================\n";
    cout << "Student ID:\t" << id << endl;
    cout << "Student Name:\t" << firstName << " " << lastName << endl;
    cout << setprecision(4) << "Average:\t" << average << endl;
    cout << "Test Scores: " << endl;

    // Printing the test scores nicely
    int scoresPerLine = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < numTests; i++)
    {
        cout << setprecision(4) << testScores[i] << "\t";
        if ((i + 1) % scoresPerLine == 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "=========================================================\n\n";
}
```

The error I'm getting is Exception thrown: write access violation. **this** was 0xCCCCCCCC and it throws the exception at a break point created at

void Student::setFirstName(string studentFirstName) at the line firstName = studentFirstName.

My question is: what exactly is preventing this from working? Am I doing something wrong? I dont' get any errors before I compile everything, so it looks like everything is built ok. I've also tried using a pass-by-reference on that member function, but that's also failing with the same response.

Comment: Get rid of `studentsPtr`. Just use `students` everywhere.

Comment: That works just fine, but part of my assignment is that I use the -> member pointer, which I thought I had to use a pointer variable for that.

Comment: Yes, you use `->` with pointers. But the code in the question doesn't use `->` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong?

Yes, definitely :)

Let's go through it:

```
Student * students = new Student[numStudents];
```

... the above allocates a dynamic array of 15 `Student` objects; so far, so good.

```
Student ** studentsPtr = &students;
```

This line is the source of the trouble.  You've declared a double-pointer `Student **` and initialized it to point to the address of the `students` pointer.  This is legal C++, but note that there is only the standalone `students` pointer -- in particular, there is not an array of `pointers-to-Student` in your program anywhere.  (There is an array of `Student` *objects* but that is not the same thing as an array of `pointers-to-Student`)

... then a bit later on, comes the actual trouble:

```
for (int index = 0; index < numStudents; index++)
{
    [...]
    studentsPtr[index]->setID(tempID);   // BOOM!
```

Here you are trying to use `studentsPtr` as if it was if it was the base-address for an array of `pointers-to-Student`, i.e. by offsetting its location by `index` pointers and dereferencing that location.  But it's not really pointing to an array-of-pointers, it is pointing to a single pointer (i.e. it is pointing to the variable `students`), so whenever `index` is non-zero, you are invoking undefined behavior and therefore (in your case) you get a crash.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy!

So I refactored my code to include a non-dynamically allocated array of Student objects and an array of pointers which each one explicitly set to each index of the students array. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Let's debug it:

Since you didn't provide a complete test case, I changed the number of students to 3 and the number of tests to 0:

> student_records.dat
>
> ```
> 1
> Foo
> Bar
> 2
> Foo2
> Bar2
> 3
> Foo3
> Bar3
> ```

My crash occurs in `setID`, but that's okay. `this` is 0xCCCCCCCC, which is the value given to uninitialized data by MSVC in debug mode. Great, the object pointer is garbage. Where does it come from? We'll go up the call stack to see:

[image: call stack]

This brings us to the following line in the loop of `main` that reads the input:

```
studentsPtr[index]->setID(tempID);
```

First, let's look at the variables:

[image: variables]

We know the object is garbage. We can verify that here. Our object is `studentsPtr[index]`, which is shown with the same uninitialized value. We also see that `studentsPtr` itself points to the proper first student. Finally, the `index` variable has the value 1, so we're on the second student.

`studentsPtr[1]` has a value that MSVC provides for uninitialized memory. Why is it uninitialized? Let's go back to the declaration:

```
Student *students = new Student[numStudents];
Student **studentsPtr = &students;
```

`studentsPtr` is set to be a pointer to a pointer to students. The inner pointer is actually an array of students. The outer pointer, however, is one solitary `Student*`. When indexing it like `studentsPtr[1]`, we go beyond the single pointer within and trample onward to a nonexistent `Student*`. Then we try to write to that and the program thankfully blows up early.

The solution is to get rid of the double pointer. All that's needed is a bunch of `Student`s. One pointer is one (unrecommended way to represent an) array:

```
Student *students = new Student[numStudents];
...
students[index].setID(tempID);
```

Now since the number of elements is known at compile-time, the recommended type would be `std::array` (`std::array<Student, numStudents> students;`), which can be used with the same syntax as the above after its declaration. If the size were not known at compile-time, the recommended type would be `std::vector`, which also shares the same syntax to access elements.

Technically, you can fulfill the `->` requirement using a `std::array` as well. Simply obtain a pointer to the element and then use the arrow:

```
(&students[index])->setID(tempID);
```

More likely, the requirement is still looking for the manual free store memory management that you're doing. It's also easy to fit the arrow into that:

```
(students + index)->setID(tempID);
```

If you really, really need the double pointer even though it serves no purpose, remember that your array is the *inner* pointer, not the outer one:

```
((*students) + index)->setID(tempID);
```

If you're thinking the arrow hinders readability in all of these scenarios, you're correct. Perhaps the instructor has something specific in mind where it does not.

What happens when the double pointer is removed?

```
=========================================================
Student ID:     1
Student Name:   Foo Bar
Average:        -nan(ind)
Test Scores:

=========================================================

=========================================================
Student ID:     2
Student Name:   Foo2 Bar2
Average:        -nan(ind)
Test Scores:

=========================================================

=========================================================
Student ID:     3
Student Name:   Foo3 Bar3
Average:        -nan(ind)
Test Scores:

=========================================================
```

Success. The average is meaningless because I simplified the input file by changing the number of tests to 0. Long story short, the debugger provides the tools that can get debugging jobs done. Just from the debugger, we reduced the problem to the double pointer pointing to only one thing instead of multiple things. That's a much smaller scope for a problem than the original one.